# Skip test depending on parameter in py.test

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test fixture with `session` scope which is parametrized, e.g.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["one", "two", "three"])
def myfixture():
    ...
```

In my directory, I have files which use `pytest.mark.usefixtures("myfixture")` and one file which contains tests  should be run only for `myfixture` with `"two"` parameter and py.test should skip it otherwise.

Are there any ways to achieve this in py.test or do I need to set a special variable in some class in `myfixture()` function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found solution myself, one can define function in `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_namespace():
    return {"param": None}
```

And in fixture function we can do:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["one", "two", "three"])
def myfixture():
    pytest.param = request.param
    # ...
```

So we can wrap test class with:

```
@pytest.mark.skipif("pytest.param == 'value'")
class TestSmth(object):
    ...
```

Comment: Good you came back to answer this.  You should accept your answer.  `+1` 

Comment: seems that hook is `deprecated` https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/hookspec.html

Comment: @xiº: The [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/historical-notes.html#string-conditions) now says "Since pytest-2.4 boolean conditions are considered preferable ... Note that string conditions will remain fully supported and you are free to use them..."

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question while trying to solve a similar use case. My solution, in case it helps anyone avoid couple of hours. It's an easy way to override the parameterisation of a fixture from a test:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["one", "two", "three"])
def myfixture():
    ...

@pytest.mark.parameterize('myfixture', ['two'], indirect=True)
def test1(myfixture):
    ...

def test2(myfixture):
    ...
```

Thanks to https://hackebrot.github.io/pytest-tricks/mark_parametrize_with_indirect/ for explaining the use of indirect!

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to do this is to use the `pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook to modify your test collection before they are run

Given your fixture as described:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", params=["one", "two", "three"])
def myfixture(request):
    ...
```

Add a custom mark to your tests:

```py
@pytest.mark.restriction("two")
def test_smth(self, myfixture):
    ...
```

Then modify your test collection with custom deselection logic:

```py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items, config):
    """ deselect test items which do not match the fixture restriction """
    deselection_items = []
    for item in items:
        # There may be a better way than regex to get the parameter
        passed_param = re.search(r'\[(.+?)\]', item.name).group(1)
        restrictions = set([mark.args[0] for mark in item.iter_markers(name='restriction')])
        if len(restrictions) > 0:
            if passed_param not in restrictions:
                deselection_items.append(item)
    items[:] = [item for item in items if item not in deselection_items]
    config.hook.pytest_deselected(items=deselection_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up writing my own decorator, which I think is reasonably easy and clean:

```py
import functools

def skip_targets(excluded_values):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            paramA = kwargs['paramA']
            if paramA in excluded_values:
                pytest.skip('Param A "{}" currently not supported'.format(paramA))
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

To deactivate a test that uses a fixture for `paramA`, you can exclude the value `X` like this:

```py
@skip_targets(['X'])
def test_param(self, paramA):
    pass
```